# URL Mapping is not working as expected for dual dispatcher config in Spring MVC with No XML

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to make a No XML Pure Annotation based Spring MVC Configuration to work using Dual Dispatchers in my sample program. However the URL mapping is not working the way it is supposed to.

First let me explain what my sample program does. My sample Program has two sections -
**a public URL section -->** `appName/ *.pub`
**a secure URL section -->** `appName/ *.sec`

Both these sections are configured to use 2 different dispatchers for view's resolution which are configured in the Application Initializer as follows:

```
public class springMVCwithHibernateMavenInitializer implements
    WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {

    // Create the Spring application context
    String[] configLocations = { "test.springMVC.config","test.springMVC.controller" };

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.refresh();
    appContext.setConfigLocations(configLocations);
    appContext.register(AppConfig.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

    /**/
    // Create the Public Dispatcher Servlet context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext publicWebMVCContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    publicWebMVCContext.register(PublicWebMVCConfig.class);

    // Register the Public Dispatcher Servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic publicDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("public-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(publicWebMVCContext));
    publicDispatcher.addMapping("*.pub");
    publicDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    /**/
    // Create the Secure Dispatcher Servlet context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext secureWebMVCContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    secureWebMVCContext.register(SecureWebMVCConfig.class);

    // Register the Secure Dispatcher Servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic secureDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("secure-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(secureWebMVCContext));
    secureDispatcher.addMapping("*.sec");
    secureDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}    
}
```

#### PublicWebMVCConfig.java --> maps url ending with ****.pub*** to physical path *WEB-INF/jsp/public/*.jsp*

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "test.springMVC.config", "test.springMVC.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class PublicWebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private final String publicURIPrefix = "/jsp/public/";
private final String uriSuffix = ".jsp";

@Bean(name = "publicViewResolver")
public ViewResolver publicViewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver publicResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    publicResolver.setPrefix(publicURIPrefix);
    publicResolver.setSuffix(uriSuffix);

    return publicResolver;
}
}
```

#### SecureWebMVCConfig.java --> maps url ending with ****.sec*** to physical path *WEB-INF/jsp/secure/*.jsp* [Code not included here]

The problem that is occurring with this code is that when I call the url with path mapping `*.pub`, it somehow is using the `secureDispatcher` instead of the `publicDispatcher` and url with path `*.sec` uses `publicDispatcher` which should not be the case.

The problem is solved when i reverse the mapping in `springMVCwithHibernateMavenInitializer` class for both dispatcher, however it is not the solution and i am not able to figure out why this is happening.

***Please help me fix this and it will be also kind of you if you could explain the reason of this problem. I could not find relative references on google for Annotation based Spring MVC program with multi Dispatcher Configuration. Any help is appreciated.***

You can download the WAR file for this sample program [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ZVy8oMfUzXQUtBWXB6NkxxN00/edit?usp=sharing) so that you can reproduce the problem. By the way program use Spring v4.0.5, deployed on Tomcat v7.0.25.

Comment: How can you tell which `Servlet` is being used?  Can you give an example of a URL you send a request to and what the result is?

Comment: Configuration is made such that `publicDispatcher` should use resolver in `PublicWebMVCConfig` and `secureDispatcher` should use resolver in `SecureWebMVCConfig`.  

URL Example: `http://localhost:8080/springMVCMavenNoXML/login.pub`  
Resulting error: requested resource (/springMVCMavenNoXML/jsp/secure/login.jsp) is not available.

It should redirect to `jsp/public/login.jsp`. instead it redirects to `jsp/secure/login.jsp` which can only happen if it is using view resolver configured for `secureDispatcher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your `@Configuration` classes, which are in the `test.springMVC.config` package, you've specified

```
 @ComponentScan({ "test.springMVC.config", "test.springMVC.controller" })
```

So each `@Configuration` class will scan and initialize component beans in those declared packages. One of those beans will be an instance of *the other* `@Configuration` class. `@Configuration` is special in that Spring will initialize the beans declared in its annotated class.

In this case, your public config will create two `ViewResolver` beans. It just so happens that it registers the secure one first and that's the one that will be used.

You can simply remove the `test.springMVC.config` package from the `@ComponentScan` of each `@Configuration` class to make this work.

Comment: @rockstar89 Right.  So when the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` that loads `PublicWebMVCConfig` initializes it, it scans the `test.springMVC.config` package and initializes a `SecureWebMVCConfig` bean which initialize its `ViewResolver` bean. (And vice versa.)